How does Bluey translate a real-world event that involved a dog?
Bluey is a functionally one-to-one version of the real world where every human is a dog.
For example, the currency has a dog on it where the queen should be. There's a royal wedding plate with two dogs in place of Prince Charles and Princess Diana. A Double Dragon arcade machine is similar to the real one with muscled dogs taking the place of the characters. There doesn't seem to be any explicitly missing piece of history, so it feels like it's intended to be one-to-one but just involving bipedal anthropomorphic dogs in place of humans. Animals besides dogs seem to exist normally as well like birds and bugs (although the concept of pets aren't brought up to my knowledge).
That's all the humans handled. However, has there ever been an instance where Bluey covered a situation that involved a dog in our world? And if so, how was the dog's involvement handled?
Edit: To clarify more explicitly, here's a specific case: in one episode there's a copy of Cujo by Stephen King at a garage sale. It's obviously a joke on how Stephen King books are often at garage sales and a wink at the subject matter of Bluey about it being the book about an evil dog. But if a character opened that book, what would they see? Would all of the characters and Cujo be dogs? Would Cujo's motivations be rewritten to be more human? Would Cujo be a different animal?

The closest thing I've noticed is the early depiction of Socks, who, like a puppy, is young enough to only walk on all fours and to only yip-yap, not talk.  Apparently anthropomorphism comes at a later stage of growth.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IQIex5HpMk

"I'm not taking instructions from a cartoon dog!" - Bandit Heeler

I think we have a Goofy-Pluto situation here.

There's a few conversations (notably in the BBQ episode and Creek) that refer to sheep herding, as if they all have a kind of second life where they act like real cattle dogs and humans exist. It's a throwaway gag so don't think too hard about it.

@magarnicle Yeah, I recall reading that Bandit is an archaeologist because dogs like digging up bones and Chile's work at the Airport was as a sniffing dog.  But I feel like they abandoned that angle pretty quickly.

Cats?
In Bluey, there's a TV series called Cat Squad which has been featured a number of times (and even has its own theme song):

For context, according to the imaginative play in the episode Shops, cats (or kittens specifically) are pets that can't talk.
This show is most likely a reference to Paw Patrol, another wildly popular children's series, which features a team of talking dogs themed around different emergency services (in a world where there are also humans and cats):


Yeah, actually, that tracks. I didn't know that Cat Squad and Paw Patrol were so similar.
